# Uniform continuous function

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=x\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}$. Is the function uniformly continuous over the interval $[-1,1)$ and $[0,1)$.
I know that I have to use the Cantor's theorem but the interval is not closed and bounded? How to do this?
And another question: If the interval includes $∞$ or $-∞$ how to prove is it uniformly continuous or not?

Maybe this question is trivial but I started studying it now.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous. Then there is some $\delta > 0$ such that
$$
| x - y | < \delta \implies | f(x) - f(y) | < 1.
$$

Now $f$ is bounded on the compacta $[-1, 1 - \frac{\delta}{2}]$. But the formula above shows that, for all $x \in (1- \frac{\delta}{2}, 1)$, 
$$f(x) \in (f(1-\frac{\delta}{2}) -1,f(1-\frac{\delta}{2}) +1),$$

so that $f$ is bounded on $[-1,1)$. But an easy calculation shows that $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = \infty$. Contradiction!

Comment: And what about if the interval includes $∞$ or $-∞$?

Comment: @spyer Since $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $[-1,1)$, it's not uniformly continuous on any larger domain either  -- hence the proof doesn't change at all.

Comment: I understand this. I was asking if there was another function how will we proceed if the interval includes infinity?

Comment: @spyer Depends on the function. There is no universal procedure.

Comment: If the function is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ and the interval is $(0,+∞)$ ?

Comment: @spyer You can use basically the same argument as above to show that this function is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1]$ and hence not on $(0, \infty)$.